# Adding a loading animation when loading in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, web, loading

I would like to add a loading animation to my website since it's loading quite a bit when entering the website. It is built in ReactJS & NodeJS, so I need to know specifically with ReactJS how to add a loading animation when initially entering the site and also when there is any loading time when rendering a new component.

So is there a way to let people on my website already, although it's not fully loaded, so I can add a loading page with some CSS3 animation as a loading screen.
The question is not really how to make a loading animation. It's more about how to integrate it into ReactJS.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Since ReactJS virtual DOM is pretty fast, I assume the biggest load time is due to asynchronous calls. You might be running async code in one of the React lifecycle event (e.g. `componentWillMount`).

Your application looks empty in the time that it takes for the HTTP call. To create a loader you need to keep the state of your async code.

**Example without using Redux**

We will have three different states in our app:

- REQUEST: while the data is requested but has not loaded yet.
- SUCCESS: The data returned successfully. No error occurred.
- FAILURE: The async code failed with an error.

While we are in the request state we need to render the spinner. Once the data is back from the server, we change the state of the app to `SUCCESS` which trigger the component re-render, in which we render the listings.

```js
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const REQUEST = 'REQUEST'
const SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS'
const FAILURE = 'FAILURE'

export default class Listings extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {status: REQUEST, listings: []}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/listing/12345')
      .then(function (response) {
        this.setState({listing: response.payload, status: SUCCESS})
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        this.setState({listing: [], status: FAILURE})
      })
  }

  renderSpinner() {
      return ('Loading...')
  }

  renderListing(listing, idx) {
    return (
      <div key={idx}>
        {listing.name}
      </div>
    )
  }

  renderListings() {
    return this.state.listing.map(this.renderListing)
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.status == REQUEST ? this.renderSpinner() : this.renderListings()
  }
}
```

**Example using Redux**
You can pretty much do the similar thing using Redux and [Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) middleware.

Thunk middleware allows us to send actions that are functions. Therefore, it allows us to run an async code. Here we are doing the same thing that we did in the previous example: we keep track of the state of asynchronous code.

```js
export default function promiseMiddleware() {
   return (next) => (action) => {
      const {promise, type, ...rest} = action

      if (!promise) return next(action)

      const REQUEST = type + '_REQUEST'
      const SUCCESS = type + '_SUCCESS'
      const FAILURE = type + '_FAILURE'

      next({...rest, type: REQUEST})

      return promise
         .then(result => {

            next({...rest, result, type: SUCCESS})

            return true
         })
         .catch(error => {
            if (DEBUG) {
               console.error(error)
               console.log(error.stack)
            }
            next({...rest, error, type: FAILURE})

            return false
         })
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think it's not what I am looking for. Once the website loaded (main index route), loading between pages is effortless. What I am trying to achieve is to have a loading animation on the initial connection to the website. I hope you know what I mean.